# MongoDB - many-to-many/few-to-few relationship schema design, without lookup performance issues

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database-design, nosql

We are developing an app that basically works similarly to Instagram, but with `groups`. Users can invite other users to groups. The members in a group share `posts` containing photos, media etc. A user has a `feed` with all the posts that have been posted recently in the groups, with paging. The users can also access posts from within the groups.

The `feed query` is slow due to the nature of our current schema design. In practice, request time will increase as the amount of data increases, which is not very scalable now when we see more users on the platform.

> **Question 1** How should we model our data, in the best possible way, using MongoDB to make our feed query faster and more scaleable?

Our current backend is built using Parse Server with MongoDB and Node.js

```
A simplified version of our schema is as follows:

Class/Document
    - Attribute

Users
    -  id
Group
    - id
    - members (array of user pointer objects)- basically an array of ids
    - admins (array of user pointer objects) - basically an array of ids
    - createdBy (pointer to user object) - basically an id of the owner of the group
Posts
    - id
    - groups (array of group pointer objects) - basically an array of ids
```

So right now, when we want to get the `posts` in a user's `feed` we have to go through the following process:

1. Go through all `groups`, checking the group's members/admins arrays for the user, and get all groups for the user
2. Go through all `posts`, checking the post’s groups array to see if post should be in the feed.

**Possible solution to Question 1** ([MongoDB - Many-to-many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267338/mongodb-many-to-many-relationship))

This would mean:

1. Have a `group array` (pointers to group objects) in the `User class`, that points to groups where the user is admin/member or owner. Have, like before, the member/admin arrays and createdBy in the Group class.
2. Have a `post array` (pointers to post objects) in the `Group class`. Have, like before, the groups array in the Post class.

   ```
   This would translate into the following schema:  

   Class/Document
       - Attribute
   Users
       -  id
       - groups (array of group pointer objects, where the user is either admin/member or owner) - basically an array of ids
   Group
       - id
       - members (array of user pointer objects)- basically an array of ids
       - admins (array of user pointer objects) - basically an array of ids
       - createdBy (pointerObject to user) - basically an id of the owner of the group
       - posts (array of post pointer objects) - basically an array of ids
   Posts
       - id
       - groups (array of group pointer objects) - basically an array of ids
   ```

Meaning, you would have two-way query ability. Downside is that you have to be careful to keep these arrays consistent with one another.

> **Question 2** Is it sensible to use MongoDB in the long run for our type of application or should we aim to migrate to, for example,
>   PostgreSQL? (I’m a bit biased as I’ve been working more with RDMS-
>   than NoSQL databases)

We will also continue extend our statistics interface for showing different activities and their `stats` in the `groups` and we are predicting that we will have more `many-to-many` situations, or `few-to-few` relationships. We have started to experiment, adding PostgreSQL to the mix. `Mirroring` the data in `MongoDB` with `PostgreSQL` and use SQL for some of the above queries that didn’t scale well with our current schema design in MongoDB. We are also thinking of gradually moving over to PostgreSQL. However, this might  be a premature decision, if we can make everything work well with MongoDB. As we will continue to extend our statistics interface, is it better to move over to using a RDMS like PostgreSQL?

All help is appreciated.
Have a great day!

Comment: MongoDB implements hierarchical data model which is not appropriate for these kind of relations. Have a look at network (graph based) data models instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer @serge! I totally agree that the hierarchical data model is not good for social relational data, would we build this from scratch then MongoDB would probably not be our first choice. But we actually have this in production. Why not use a well proven relational database like PostgreSQL instead of a graph database? PostgreSQL have JSONB support and so on. What is the largest benefit of a graph database like Neo4J in comparison to a relational database in our case? To me existing graph database solutions don't seem as mature. I've heard some stories, though they were vague.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your point. You agreed that hierarchical data model is not good for this domain but suggested to use PostgreSQL at the same manner.